# Is there a delay between the loading of opencv.js and it being ready in 3.4.6 and newer?

Tags: opencv

I'm using opencv.js and there appears to be a delay between the script load and e.g. the ability to call `new cv.Mat()` without throwing an exception. Is there a better workaround than waiting a second after the opencv script's `onload=` handler is called? Older versions, 3.2?, seem not to have this problem.

Answer (score 0):

`opencv.js` can be used like any `emscripten` module. To run your code only when opencv is ready, create a global `Module` object with an `onRuntimeInitialized` function to call your code.

```
<script>
  function openCvReady() {
    console.log("OpenCV.js is ready");
  }

  var Module = {
    onRuntimeInitialized() { openCvReady(); }
  };
</script>

<script async src="opencv.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

See also https://emscripten.org/docs/api_reference/module.html#Module.onRuntimeInitialized